# Exercises with String using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function called `remove_duplicates` which will take one argument called `string`.
This `string` input will `only have characters between a-z`.
The function should remove all repeated characters in the string and return a tuple with two values:

- A new string with only unique, sorted characters.
- The total number of duplicates dropped.

For example:

- `remove_duplicates('aaabbbac')` should produce `('abc')`
- `remove_duplicates('a')` should produce `('a', 0)`
- `remove_duplicates('thelexash')` should produce `('aehlstx', 2)`

**My Code:**

```
    def remove_duplicates(string):

        for string in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":

            k = set(string)

            x = len(string) - len(set(string))

            return k, x

    print(remove_duplicates("aaabbbccc"))
```

Expected Output:

I'm expecting it to print `({a, b, c}, 6)` instead it prints `({a}, 0)`.

What is wrong with my code above? Why it isn't producing what I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the expected result if you don't iterate over each char in the string.

I've commented your code so you'll can see the difference between your script and mine.

---

**Non-working commented code:**

```
def remove_duplicates(string):

    #loop through each char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and call it "string"
    for string in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":

        #create variable k that holds a set of 1 char because of the loop
        k = set(string)

        # create a variable x that holds the difference between 1 and 1 = 0
        x = len(string) - len(set(string))

        #return these values in each iteration
        return k, x

print(remove_duplicates("aaabbbccc"))
```

**Outputs:**

```
({'a'}, 0)
```

---

**Working code:**

```
def remove_duplicates(string):

    #create variable k that holds a set of each unique char present in string
    k = set(string)

    # create a variable x that holds the difference between 1 and 1 = 0
    x = len(string) - len(set(string))

    #return these values
    return k, x

print(remove_duplicates("aaabbbccc"))
```

**Outputs:**

```
({'b', 'c', 'a'}, 6)
```

**P.s.:** if you want your results to be in order, you can change `return k, x` to `return sorted(k), x`, but then the output will be a list.

```
(['a', 'b', 'c'], 6)
```

---

**EDIT:** if you want your code runs only if certain condition is met - for example, runs only if string don't have any number - you can add an if/else clause:

**Example Code:**

```
def remove_duplicates(s):

    if not s.isdigit():
        k = set(s)
        x = len(s) - len(set(s))
        return sorted(k), x
    else:
        msg = "This function only works with strings that doesn't contain any digits.."
        return msg


print(remove_duplicates("aaabbbccc"))
print(remove_duplicates("123123122"))
```

**Outputs:**

```
(['a', 'b', 'c'], 6)
This function only works with strings that doesn't contain any digits..
```

Comment: Ok, how do I restrict the string to be an alphabet only for the code to run. Like your code will also run for "22233377".    That's what am trying to do, by "for xx in TTT" run

Comment: You'll have to add an `if/else` clause. I've updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: HELP! I have been trying to convert the output from this    (['a', 'b', 'c'], 6)     to ("abc", 6).

Comment: Change `return sorted(k), x` to `return ''.join(sorted(k)), x`

Comment: It worked fine. but kindly explain that method to me. you joined the sorted set to a string. so the result becomes a string right??????

Comment: You're correct! I just used `join`  to merge each item in the `sorted(k)` `list` with the `''` operator.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the function at the first instance where a character is found. So it returns for the first "a".

Try this instead :

```
def remove_duplicates(string):
    temp = set(string)
    return temp,len(string) - len(temp)


print(remove_duplicates("aaabbbccc"))
```

Output :

```
({'c', 'b', 'a'}, 6)
```

If you want to remove everything expect alphabets (as you mentioned in comments) try this:

```
def remove_duplicates(string):
    a= set()
    for i in string:
        if i.isalpha() and i not in a:
            a.add(i)
    return a,len(string) - len(a)
```

Comment: Ok, how do I restrict the string to be an alphabet only for the code to run. Like your code will also run for "22233377".    That's what am trying to do, by "for xx in TTT" run

Comment: I have updated my answer . Are you sure u want a set as output rather than a string?

Comment: Your earlier answer is ok. I just need additional clause to make sure that it doesn't accept "2223333" for string rather only "abc....z"

Comment: Check the second part of my answer. Doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the function will return after iterating the 1st character.
As `string` refers to the first char in the input string. I think you are trying to iterate over the `string` variable character-by-character.
For this, you can use `collections.Counter` which performs the same computation more efficiently.

However, we can work with an alternate solution which doesn't involve computing the count of each character in the given string.

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    unique_characters = set(s) # extract the unique characters in the given string
    new_sorted_string = ''.join(sorted(unique_characters)) # create the sorted string with unique characters
    number_of_duplicates = len(s) - len(unique_characters) # compute the number of duplicates in the original string
    return new_sorted_string, number_of_duplicates
```

Comment: Ok, how do I restrict the string to be an alphabet only for the code to run. Like your code will also run for "22233377".    That's what am trying to do, by "for xx in TTT" run

Comment: @wapadunk I am unable to understand what are you trying to refer by string and alphabet? A string is a Python `type`.

Comment: Your earlier answer is ok. I just need additional clause to make sure that it doesn't accept "2223333" for string rather only "abc....z"

Answer (score -1):

```
def remove_duplicates(s):
    unique_characters = set(s) # extract the unique characters in the given 
string
    new_sorted_string = ''.join(sorted(unique_characters)) # create the sorted string with unique characters
    number_of_duplicates = len(s) - len(unique_characters) # compute the number of duplicates in the original string
    return new_sorted_string, number_of_duplicates
```